# Decoding a Openid token with the openid-client library

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, openid

I'm working with openid-client library, and I got the entire login process working (Yay Me).

And then when it callbacks to the sever and I don't know what to do with what came back. I assume I can decode the code, but not sure how.

```
const { Issuer, generators } = require('openid-client');
var idIssuer;
var client;

const login = async (req, res)=> {


    if (!idIssuer){
        idIssuer = await Issuer.discover(process.env.LOGIN_URI);
    }

    if (!client){

    client = new idIssuer.Client({
        client_id: process.env.LOGIN_APPID,
        client_secret: process.env.LOGIN_APPSECRET,
        redirect_uris: [process.env.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URI],
        response_types: ['code'],

      });
    }


    let url = client.authorizationUrl({
        scope:process.env.LOGIN_SCOPES,
        state:  base64url(JSON.stringify({ state: process.env.LOGIN_APPID })),
      });

      res.redirect(url);

}

const callBack = async  (req, res)=>{
    if (!idIssuer){
        idIssuer = await Issuer.discover(process.env.LOGIN_URI);
    }

    if (!client){

    client = new idIssuer.Client({
        client_id: process.env.LOGIN_APPID,
        client_secret: process.env.LOGIN_APPSECRET,
        redirect_uris: [process.env.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URI],
        //response_types: ['code'],

      });
    }

    console.log(req.query);
    /*
    {
        code: 's5LI-16HvCSnmi94Q74UEGmlNtE6utmGY7YaOV72s_k.C6Vt2v8uL4loPeq3YGA8bRyR8dVpU1wAEgHyLZadMhQ',
        scope: 'openid',
        state: 'eyJzdGF0ZSI6IlZwWkVIZVhYNnczbDh0R3JBZHFFdVZBdnlKV2NlenZVRE9FRzVDS1BRcnpZQjhkVWs4MHNHMmVoOUFMMHp0R2NRTWdMNVJtQV9MOEhpZjEzcEZTLXFBPT0ifQ'
      }
      */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the code you got back, you should use it to call the OAuth server again and exchange it for the real access and IDtoken.

For example

POST /connect/token
CONTENT-TYPE application/x-www-form-urlencoded

```
client_id=client1&
client_secret=secret&
grant_type=authorization_code&
code=hdh922&
redirect_uri=https://myapp.com/callback
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily follow the [quick-start](https://github.com/panva/node-openid-client#authorization-code-flow). What you do next is take the callback parameters and use [`client.callback()`](https://github.com/panva/node-openid-client/blob/main/docs/README.md#clientcallbackredirecturi-parameters-checks-extras) to get the ID Token, Access Token, and optionally a Refresh Token.